# Graphql request getting cancelled in the first time and then giving a successful response with the same query parameter

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, strapi

I am using Apollo client + Graphql + React in my project and I am facing a weird issue in Graphql requests. I am not able to understand the reason to cancelling the request.
Graphql request getting cancelled in the first time and then giving a successful response with the same query parameter.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294001/apollo-graphql-requests-are-canceled) but it seems like [Component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/components/#gatsby-focus-wrapper) is deprecated now in apollo client.

Here is the screenshot of Graphql requests.
It's getting cancelled in the first time and again it's giving a successful response

[image: Console request]

Comment: Are you using Observables? On which operation/Condition are you calling the graphql

Comment: whenever I am landing on this page.

Comment: it can be structural problem, doesn't matter HoC/components/hooks ... some component renders other component making request (creates observable) then the 1st one is rerendered for whatever reason (prop/variable changed)

Comment: But the same bunch of code is running fine on another instance.

Comment: Having same issue. @jay found any solution?

Comment: @yogesnsamy Not now, I will update here when I found the solution.